# article extraction from newspaper image in python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv

[image: first image: this is the image I tried Run length smoothing algorithm horizontal and vertical with some pixel value depends on the dimension of the image]

[image: second image: Another image to extract article by increasing the pixel value but merging with other articles]

I tried extracting articles from the newspaper image, but headings are being separated with rlsa algorithm horizontal and vertical of some pixel value in the first image. If I tried with more pixel value, articles are merging which is showed in second image. Can anyone suggest the best method to separate articles from the image in python and opencv?

## This loop is for run-length-smoothing-algorithm-horizontal on the image

```
    for i in range(1,a):
        c = 1
        for j in range(1, b):
            if im_bw[i, j] == 0:
                if (j-c) <= 10:
                    im_bw[i, c:j] = 0
                
                c = j
            
        
        if (b - c) <= 10:
            im_bw[i, c:b] = 0
```

## This loop is for run-length-smoothing-algorithm-vertical on the image

```
    for i in range(1, b):
        c = 1
        for j in range(1, a):
            if im_bw[j, i] == 0:
                if (j-c) <= 9:
                    im_bw[c:j, i] = 0
                
                c = j
            
        
        if (b - c) <= 9:
            im_bw[c:b, i] = 0
```

a is number of rows
b is number of columns of an binary image

How algorithm worked on binary image and red mark shows the merging of articles

[image]

Comment: Please add your code to your question, what libraries and functions are you using?

Comment: I didnt add any libraries, I run rlsa horizontal and vertical algo on the images.

Comment: checkout now. code is added to the main post @agold

Comment: The first image's results seems to be a bit better, maybe you can try to combine the articles based on some heuristic (e.g. group them if they don't have a large font title).

Comment: @agold I need full article with the title should separate. Can you elaborate more about the heuristic you're talking about.

Comment: I don't have a clear solution, but just some ideas. The problem is that there is not a clear solution that works always, that's why you should search for some heuristics. To get some ideas I'd search for articles about this, for example: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.0999.pdf, http://allenai.org/content/publications/clark_divvala.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I have an approach worked for most of the images.

1. Binary conversion of color/gray scale images using PIL/Opencv.
2. Remove pictures from image as contours with largest area compared to
   average area of all the contours present in the image.
3. Remove lines using **canny** edge filter and **houghlines**
4. Use **RLSA**(run length smoothing algorithm) on this binary image. Description and Code for this **RLSA** can be found on this repository https://github.com/Vasistareddy/python-rlsa

Removing lines helps because some e-papers keeps lines as article separator.
We can achieve better results with more processing of the images. Heuristics like average width, average height, average area can be implemented on the contours left on the image after applying above steps to achieve better results.

Coming to the above question, the articles always with the white background. Without white background are clearly "Ads" or "pictures" or "miscellaneous" stuff. **Removing pictures from the above 4 mentioned steps clears** solves this issue.

PS: Choosing a value for **RLSA** horizontal and vertical is always mystery. Since the gap of the article varies from edition to edition.

Edit:

the above problem is basically applying Heuristics. Read through this

https://medium.com/@vasista/extract-title-from-the-image-documents-in-python-application-of-rlsa-58f91237901f