# Extract Gujarati (Language Supported by Google Input Tools) Text from Newspaper Articles

Tags: python, text, extract, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to Extract (Gujarati Language) Text from Newspaper articles (Photos / Digital Copy),

Currently I manually crop the articles into small pieces as most of the tools extract text horizontally, this does not work with columnar structure of newspaper articles.

Then, I merge all the images vertically, and upload it to google drive.

Then, I open the image with google docs, where I get image along with the text with good accuracy (As Gujarati Language is supported by Google Input Tools).

I am trying to automate all of the above tasks so that I only give newspaper article as input and get the final text output.

I have heard about python automation script, but no idea of how to work with it.

---

So, Ultimately I need 2 tasks to be performed in series:
(1) Identify blocks in sequence from newspaper article,
(2) Image -> Text Conversion

Here, is a sample article image:

[image]

Help me with "How I can speed up my task ?"

Comment: Can you share What you have tried till now. This seems to be an easy task. I suggest you should read from articles online.

Comment: I have tried many software and mobile apps, that are dedicated to extract Gujarati text from images, (I dont have the names with me now) but they have little accuracy compared with Google Docs. Moreover, all the solutions requires to manually identify the sequence of paragraphs , as newspaper articles may have multiple columns. I have been advised earlier that python have many good libraries for text extraction, but I am not sure if it works for Gujarati.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get yourself familiar with [openCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_intro/py_intro.html).To Begin with here is the basic idea:

```
# convert the image to binary
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('news.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert2grayscale
(thresh, binary) = cv2.threshold(gray, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU) # convert2binary
cv2.imshow('binary', binary)
(_, contours, _) = cv2.findContours(~binary,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 
# find contours
for contour in contours:
    """
    draw a rectangle around those contours on main image
    """
    [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0, 255, 0), 1)
cv2.imshow('contour', image)
```

After that read about [Python-tesseract](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/)(optical character recognition (OCR) tool for python).

I am mentioning some useful sources which may be helpful to you:

1. [article-extraction-from-newspaper-image-in-python-and-opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299412/article-extraction-from-newspaper-image-in-python-and-opencv)
2. [finding-blocks-of-text-in-an-image-using-python-opencv-and-numpy](https://www.danvk.org/2015/01/07/finding-blocks-of-text-in-an-image-using-python-opencv-and-numpy.html)
3. [opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/)